# Is there a way to disable built-in deadlines on App Engine dev_appserver?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, sdk

I realize that `dev_appserver.py` is meant to simulate the production App Engine environment as much as possible, but I'm having trouble debugging an app locally due to slow connection issues (I keep getting `DeadlineExceededError` exceptions). Since it's not the connection itself that I'm concerned about, is there any way to temporarily disable/extend the timeout for `urlfetch` (and others) just for the development environment? Unfortunately, the app does need to be connected to a live webservice, and I can't just patch in a dummy response in this case.

This may be a simple fix for someone who knows more about the innards of the SDK, but I haven't had much luck in my Googling. I would appreciate any help or advice you may have.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When running on the development server, you could set a higher default urlfetch deadline:

```
import os
if os.environ['SERVER_SOFTWARE'].startswith('Dev'):
    from google.appengine.api import urlfetch
    urlfetch.set_default_fetch_deadline(60)
```

Comment: Thanks! `set_default_fetch_deadline()` was just the thing I needed.